# Cron Job scheduler

Tags: scheduled-apex

I have a trigger that calls a schedulable class.  The trigger fires on insert and I want to set my schedulable class to run 1 hour and 1 minute after the insert occurs.

I was calling my schedulable class like this:

```
OrderApprovalDeadlineScheduler.scheduleIt('0 1 1 * * ? *', newCollection);
```

I can see my apex job has been scheduled with a status of pending, but the it is well past the 1 hour and 1 minute and I would have expected the job to have run by now.  Is my Cron Exp wrong?

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is not actually scheduling it for 1 hr and 1 minute in the future but rather for 1:01 am in the morning every day. Probably not what you intended.

If you want to run it just 1 hour and 1 minute in the future, you could do something like the following:

```
Datetime futureTime = Datetime.now().addHours(1).addMinutes(1);
String futureTimeCronString = '0 ' + futureTime.minute() + ' ' + futureTime.day() + ' ' + futureTime.month() + ' * ' + futureTime.year();
System.schedule('OrderApprovalDeadlineScheduler', futureTimeCronString, new OrderApprovalDeadlineScheduler());
```

This has not been tested but should be close to what you want. It builds up a Cron Expression for a specific date and then schedules the class to run. It does assume that your `OrderApprovalDeadlineScheduler` class implements the `Schedulable` interface.

However, I would caution against actually setting up scheduled jobs from a trigger.  It is potential that the trigger will get called over 100 times before one of the jobs runs, at which point you will have hit a governor limit and the process will fail. See the documentation [here](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/index_Left.htm#StartTopic=Content/apex_methods_system_system.htm#apex_System_System_schedule)